# how do i edit this newton method in python to loop until the difference between consecutive guesses is less than 0.00001?

Tags: python

how do i edit this newton method in python to loop until the difference between consecutive guesses is less than 0.00001?

```
import math
def main():
    x = eval(input("Enter the number to calculate square root of: "))    
    guess = x/2.0
    print ("Initial guess is", guess)
    n = eval(input("How many times to improve the guess: "))
    print()

    for cnt in range(n):
        guess = (guess+x/guess)/2
        print ("Improvement", cnt+1, ": next guess is", guess)


    print()
    print ("The final guess is", guess)
    print ("math.sqrt(x) returns", math.sqrt(x))      

main()
```

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `eval()`, use `float()` and `int()`, respectively. `eval()` carries some security risks; a malicious user could enter arbitrary Python code when prompted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `break` out of the loop:

```
for cnt in range(n):
    old_guess = guess
    guess = (guess + x/guess)/2
    print ("Improvement", cnt+1, ": next guess is", guess)
    if abs(old_guess-guess) < 0.00001:
        break

print()
print ("The final guess (after {0} improvements) is {1}".format(cnt+1, guess))
print ("math.sqrt(x) returns {0}".format(math.sqrt(x)))
```

Comment: awesome! thats great, i was so close a couple of times, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I would  use an infinite loop with a break on a condition :

```
def main():
    x = float(input("Enter the number to calculate square root of: "))
    guess = x/2.0
    print ("Initial guess is", guess)
    delta = float(input("Required precision : "))

    print()
    cnt = 0

    while True:
        old = guess
        cnt += 1
        guess = (guess+x/guess)/2
        print ("Improvement", cnt+1, ": next guess is", guess)
        if abs(guess - old) < delta: break


    print()
    print ("The final guess is ", guess, " in ", cnt, " passes")



    print ("math.sqrt(x) returns", math.sqrt(x))
```